# How to fix hover correctly in a Text Block with corner radius?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I put hover effect over my Text Block with corner radius, but when I pass the mouse over Text Block, the hover shown whithout corner radius. This the code that I am using:

```
<Border Margin="0,0,0,0"
                BorderThickness="5"
                Background="#FF7AA0CD"
                CornerRadius="8">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="10">
                Texto a mostrarse
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property ="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property= "Background" Value="Green"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need change style from textblock to border control like this code :

```
   <Border Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF7AA0CD"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="8"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property ="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property= "Background" Value="Green"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>

            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="10">
            Texto a mostrarse               
        </TextBlock>
    </Border>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's run very well.